# Do the class of Construction Heuristic that does or does not change previous decisions have a name?

Tags: algorithms, heuristics

I'm writing a paper where I am discussing different types of construction heuristics.

One type does not change previous decisions when adding new elements to the solution. I'd call them "immutable", as the (partial) solution is immutable during construction. This behavior is known in many (possibly most) construction heuristics.

The other type can change/adapt previous decisions (at least to some extend) when adding new elements. I'd call them "mutable", as the partial solution can be changed during construction.

My question is: Does anybody know a name for those types or for this characteristics of construction heuristics (including a citation) that is already "known" in the scientific community? Or am I the first to discuss this feature (probably not)?

Comment: The idea of a greedy heuristic is certainly relevant but might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: True. A greedy heuristic is *usually* what i call "immutable". The other direction is not necessarily true.